# Waiting for an OLE Action - auto "click" ok?

Tags: excel, vba

There a lot of threads about VBA waiting on an OLE action, but most of them seem to be at least slightly different than mine, involving eventual crashes, etc.

I'm using Excel VBA and a COM api to do some testing of a third party application (basically looping over thousands of files, passing a command to the other app, and moving along).  I get the "Waiting on an OLE Action" intermiddently, and when it comes up, all I need to do is press the "OK" button and everything resumes as expected.

I don't think suppressing the message is what I want, that would just cause my code to hang, I think, but is there a way I can mimick the "clicking ok" when the error does occur?  Or am I stuck babysitting this code?

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

You might try using `Application.Wait` or WinAPI `Sleep` to slow the process.

You might also try using VBA `DoEvents` to be sure the OS is taking care of other events.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the COM API in order to **remove VBA's message filter**. I firstly found this [here](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.excel.programming/c/ct8NRT-o7rs/m/jawi42S8Ci0J). Then, it has been used in some other threads. I will show you the API declaration to be used for 64 bit Office:

1. Copy this code on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoRegisterMessageFilter Lib "OLE32.DLL" _
              (ByVal lFilterIn As Long, ByRef lPreviousFilter) As LongPtr
```

2. Copy the next code in the same module:

```
Sub KillMessageFilter()  'Original script Rob Bovey   
    '''https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/ct8NRT-o7rs/jawi42S8Ci0J

    Dim lMsgFilter As Long

    ''' Remove the message filter before calling Reflections.
    CoRegisterMessageFilter 0&, lMsgFilter

    ''' Call your code here!!!

    ''' Restore the message filter after calling Reflections.
    CoRegisterMessageFilter lMsgFilter, lMsgFilter
End Sub
```

But you must know that **if the process really has been blocked for some reason this will prevent you from receiving any notification about that**...

Comment: @Mykenk: Did you find some time to test the above suggestion?